# acessing dbcc_name from DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE win32 programming

Tags: usb

I have some c code with me which detects the usb cable removal and insertion.

I found one structure `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE` which is having `dbcc_name` as member. but I don't know which pointer to type cast to this structure to access `dbcc_name`.

How can I get the device name of the inserted device.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast a `DEV_BROADCAST_HEADER*` to a `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE*`. You are allowed to do so if and only if `dbch_devicetype==DBT_DEVTYP_DEVICEINTERFACE`.

You get`DEV_BROADCAST_HEADER*` as the `LPARAM` of `WM_DEVICECHANGE`.

To do something useful with `dbcc_name,` you have to pass it to `SetupDiOpenDeviceInterface()`. This will give you a `SP_DEVICE_INTERFACE_DATA` with one `SP_DEVINFO_DATA`. You can then call functions like `SetupDiGetDeviceRegistryProperty` to learn more about the device.

Comment: Good question, it's not documented as being empty. I presume it could be empty when it's a new device (i.e. never been connected to the PC before), and it's still being installed. But in that case I would expect a new broadcast message when the device is completely installed, that time with `dbcc_name` set. (Note: speculation, I never saw this happen)

Answer (score 1):

Please notice the CodeSet. If it is Unicode. The data is \\0......