# Use EnumDisplaySettings with non-standard Device Name

Tags: c++, winapi

I have have found out a monitors' **device name** by inspecting the value `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name` and I am attempting to use that device name inside the function `EnumDisplaySettings()` (the device name is the first parameter of that function).

**My Problem:** The function `EnumDisplaySettings()` always returns 0, ie, fails. I believe it fails because MSDN says the first parameter of `EnumDisplaySettings()` should be a `DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName returned from EnumDisplayDevices` whereas my device name is from `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name`.

Using `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name` I get the device name `\\?\DISPLAY#GSM3AD7#5&20a3f50d&0&UID513#{866519b5-3f07-4c97-b7df-24
c5d8a8ccb8}` for my second monitor whereas `EnumDisplayDevices()` gives me the device name `\\.\DISPLAYV1`.

Is it possible to use EnumDisplaySettings() where the 1st parameter is a device name retrieved from the function DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name?

**The reason why I ask is:** when a second monitor gets connected to the computer I want to change that monitors display settings. But upon monitor connection I am notified of its device name through `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name` which (as I explained above) is a different name to what EnumDisplayDevices() returns for the exact same device. And I dont know how I could identify that second monitor by enumerating though all display devices using EnumDisplayDevices()? Any ideas how I could enumerate though all display devices using EnumDisplayDevices() and identify the correct monitor/device that was just connected to the computer?

Answer (score 1):

I can't guarantee it, but I'd *guess* that a display device retains its name as long as it remains connected.

On that assumption, I'd run `EnumDisplayDevices` when your program starts. When the new monitor is connected, use `EnumDisplayDevices` again, and compare the list of devices to your previous list, then `EnumDisplaySettings` on whichever device was newly added to the list.

When you're done with that, replace the old list with the new list, and you're ready for the next time the user plugs in another monitor.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at these previous answers for clues to help you turn a `DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE.dbcc_name` value into a suitable `DISPLAY_DEVICE.DeviceName` value:

[acessing dbcc_name from DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE win32 programming](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1075173/65863)

[How to get friendly device name from DEV_BROADCAST_DEVICEINTERFACE and Device Instance ID](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2223452/65863)